# Merge two observables into new one

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have to merge the result of 2 different kind of http request:

- Request 1 : get proyects. Returns an `Observable<ProjectDTO[]>`
- Request 2: depending on the numbers of projects, I have to do N calls (one per project in the list in the first call). Returns an object `ItemsProject`

With this I receive the counters of items per project. The DTO's

```
ProjectDTO {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

ItemsProject {
 idProject: number;
 itemsCount: number;
}
```

In the view, I have to display only two things: `project name and items per project`.

What I do is the following:

```
    this.vlService.getProjects().pipe(
        mergeMap(projects => {
          this.projects = projects;
          return forkJoin(
            projects.map(project => {
              const projectCount: ItemsProject = {
                idProject: project.idProjects,
                count: 0,
              };
              return this.vlService.getTotalItemsPerProject(projectCount);
            })
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log('VCOMP | result --> ', result)
      });
```

It works, but in the result I have an array of `ItemsProjects`. Then, I should replace the `ItemProject.idProject` by `Project.name`.

As a result, i want an array of items like this:

```
ProjectCounter {
 name: string;
 items: number;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing the project itself on in the stream, so you can still access the name at the end and don't break your interface structure.

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
this.vlService.getProjects().pipe(
  mergeMap(projects => from(projects).pipe(
    concatMap(project => forkJoin({
      project: of(project),
      items: this.vlService.getTotalItemsPerProject(projectCount).pipe(first())
    })),
    toArray()
  ))
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log('VCOMP | result --> ', result)
});
```

This should result in an array of objects with `project: ProjectDTO` and `items: ItemsProject[]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use rxjs operator forkjoin - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Rxjs operator zip gives them in an array - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip